# Locally defined JavaScript Functions works in All Page

Tags: javascript, ajax, smartadmin

I am using PHPAjax Version of [SmartAdmin Template](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/smartadmin-responsive-webapp-WB0573SK0),

in which i am writing some script for specific page,

```
$(document).on('change', '#vehicle_id', function(){
  var vehicle_id = $('#vehicle_id').val();
  var url = '<?php echo site_url('processor/#../tyres/check_current_km/'); ?>'+vehicle_id;
  window.location.href = url;
});
```

but it works on every page, suppose i have defined this function on a.php, it also works on b.php

Comment: May be this template is created using angularjs, so your scripts will loaded only one time, and the parts of pages will changing in that case.

Comment: i m defining functions in that page only..is there any way to destroy functions in javascript?

Comment: check your source code in b.php, is this function is also available there?

Comment: no it is not there in b.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your listener is implemented on the document, so most likely both the pages are included/ rendered in the same document and hence the script is applied to the complete document.

If you would like to constraint your script to one page then create page specific unique id and apply listener on that. e.g.('#pageA-vehicle_id').

Comment: after so many days, i found problem in this method too. when i load a.php, then moves to b.php and then again loads a.php.. a.php's functions runs twice.

Comment: That is probably because you are adding multiple listeners to it, when you load the a.php again. Make sure you register(on-page-create) and de-register(on-page-change) listeners appropriately.